# How will the users know that a "citation required" banner has been added to one of their answers?

Tags: support, answers, post-notices

I don't think that currently there is a feature which automatically notifies the users (Correct me in your answers if I'm wrong here).

So, it seems there are only two plausible solutions:

1. The users have to come repeatedly back to all of their answers and manually do the checking (This is of course absurd and not a solution at all IMO).
2. The Moderator, who has added the banner/notice, should always leave a comment under the answer telling why the notice has been added and what the user is required to do to get it removed.

But, unfortunately, that is not happening all the time (That is why this post).

If such being the case, the very purpose of adding the notices will get defeated.

- How will the users know that a "citation required" banner has been added to one of their answers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Users will get inbox message for ["citation needed"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/125660) post notice. So, there's no need to take any extra step to notify users.

Comment: Oh that's great I was not aware that there is already a feature like that.

Comment: @Rickross intentionally forget to cite sources in one of your answer to get aware with how notification works! Haha ; Btw, you can advance search `hasnotice:1 user:me is:answer` for findings