# Why "citation required" banner doesn't appear in Android Stack Exchange app?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Earlier (in Dec2017), I noticed that "citation banner" doesn't appear in Android Stack Exchange app.

But after looking at [How will the users know that a "citation required" banner has been added to one of their answers?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1451/how-will-the-users-know-that-a-citation-required-banner-has-been-added-to-one) post, I thought there might have been some update on this but still I don't see citation banners in SE app.

Below are screenshots from one of the latest posts where citation banner was added:

**App**:

[Citation banner **not** visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AvZh9.png)

**Browser**:

[Citation banner visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iaJBk.png)

Comment: @Sarvabhouma "I don't understand why it has a citation banner at first place. It had sources already" that's not in the scope of this Q...I just gave this as an example...u can install app and check other citation banners too..

Comment: There are many things missing in mobile web and Android App. I guess it's a [meta-tag:status-bydesign]. This is not a discussion question I guess.

Comment: FR posted in 2013: [Post notice does not appear in Android app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/207629/260388)

Comment: @Pandya There is no update on this feature-request since "Nov 15 '13"...

Comment: @YDS yes, [Why has Stack Exchange stopped working on the Android app?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/272122/260388)