# Feature request for ‘federalising’ the citation banner and flagging comments on mobile device, etc

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I’d like to request the following 4 features:

#### 1. Citation banner

The citation banner is a special feature in our community. This banner can only be added by mods. Recently we faced a shortage of mods due to which some low quality content may have been overlooked. Further at time mods maybe busy to handle flags. As a result, I’d request an option whereby the community themselves can vote to add a citation banner, similar to the close and reopen review queues. 3-5 votes to add citation banner. This will save the moderators’ from a headache

#### 2. Comment Flagging (if any) from a Mobile phone:

Currently comments appear with only the option to upvote without the option to flag. For example:

[image]

As a result some comments necessary to flag, especially owing to them being rude, may get left out.

#### 3. Number of views per question on Mobile device.

Currently on a mobile device, the number of views is not visible. It appears as follows:

[image]

Since there’s little space, below the number of answers, adding number of views would be appreciated too.

#### 4. Grouping deleted answers under a drop down.

This applies to both mobile and desktop. Currently in some highly active questions we see many deleted answers and have to scroll down to see some proper answers. For example, in the post : [Is Atma affected by karma?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/36993/is-atma-affected-by-karma/46720#46720), we see two deleted posts before two normal answers (with votes). Meaning the deleted answers are ranking higher, before the other two.

As such, I’d request a slight modification where all deleted answers are shifted right to the bottom under a drop down. Whenever anyone wants to refer to any deleted answer, they can click the drop down and view the deleted answers.

Or simply, if no drop down, then at least each deleted answer instead of displaying the entire post with comments should be shortened to a single bar indicating the name of the user, date and maybe number of votes. Not the entire post. If someone wants to see the entire thing, they may click on an arrow provided on the side which expands the content of the answer.

It saves scrolling.

Thank you.

Comment: About that citation banner request, TheDestroyer and I were discussing about it just few days back. Yes we can work on it.

Comment: And grouping deleted answers feature is already present. The link you shared is a link to a deleted answer post. Clicking to which will take you to deleted answer itself. Or is it not the case?

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto cool. For deleted: yes the link goes to that answer, but even when you click on a link to the question, the deleted answers are displayed first.

Comment: Just to clarify, is this the mobile web version, or the mobile app version (which is already dead now)? If it's on the mobile web, you may try using the "full site" view which is linked at the very bottom of the page. The mobile web version is not in active development since SE is now focusing on the more responsive full-site view (for both PC and mobile).

Comment: Related https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1453/why-citation-required-banner-doesnt-appear-in-android-stack-exchange-app

Comment: I got to know earlier that there is less staff to build mobile view..there is work around though..if u use mobile browser then, browser itself gives an option to view the site similar to desktop..in Chrome, it' called "Desktop site"..

Comment: Thank you Andrew and YDS

Comment: Please split multiple Feature-Requests in to separate questions

Comment: @Pandya Namaste welcome back sir