# Changing the policy of deleting unsourced answers

Tags: discussion, answers, sources-and-citations

Welcome to the *Graduated* Hinduism Stack Exchange! :)

[Directly Deleting unsourced answers without increasing moderator burden with 2 flags per post](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2323/277) has been proposed in the month of Oct'21 which seems to have gotten a good response from the community. This post is now being posted for inviting discussion on it. Let's first try to understand the difference in action, to be taken upon finding unsourced answers, between the present policy and the proposed one.

### [Present Policy](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/803/277)

<sup>Note: The exclusion criteria are denoted as `T1` for the time criterion, `E1` and `E2` for the exclusion criteria following the sequence in which they're described [here](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2181/277)</sup>

[image]

### Proposed Policy

[image]

Basically, we'll be implementing something like *"shoot at sight"* for unsourced answers, by **nullifying the whole concept of time duration and exclusion** which had been introduced with [the policy](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/803/277) and had been refined with [an update](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2181/277).

Actually we, the moderator team was not sure whether it would be a good idea to implement this proposal, since, before the introduction of the policy first time in 2017, this type of action, i.e directly deleting unsourced answers without giving time for the OP to understand, used to be partially objected to by the community at that time [which eventually lead](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/786/277) us to fabricating the policy. However, considering the drawback of the present policy - [unsourced answers living on the site](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2116/277) for a very long time, and looking at the eligibility of the OP to flag for undeletion, we requested the CMs to guide us and they have asked us to post on meta for getting a consensus from the community.

**So, please provide your feedback on this - Whether you agree with implementing the proposed policy or not. To do so, upvote the relevant answer below, corresponding to the policy, that you want implemented. You may also propose a better solution if any.**

<sub>I have tried presenting the policy actions in a flow chart to make it logically and easily understandable. I'm sharing those [present-policy.odg](https://upload.disroot.org/r/z_Sam936#2tf878oXQs8rOQmGG2USPfFvO4CiVOUz+S5b24bgg/E=) and [proposed-policy.odg](https://upload.disroot.org/r/a0B03_Ev#PUKNBM8GrlpB7vhyCGYPNYFRcWNa6FZlHWB9AWuzSpc=) files which may be useful for quick editing in case you want to propose something different.</sub>

Comment: Excellent response. It’s the correct way forward since it has also been repeatedly advised by the CMs :))

Comment: I got bit confused in "Proposed Policy"...Can a post be deleted without adding notice? if so that doesn't sound good to me..

Comment: @YDS read this: [Directly Deleting unsourced answers without increasing moderator burden with 2 flags per post](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2323/277). While deleting the mods will be putting a comment for deletion

Comment: okay.. @Adiyarkku

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Implement the proposed policy change

**Upvote this post** if you agree with implementing the **proposed policy** as represented below:

[image]

<sup>**Note**: Do not downvote this post if you disagree with this option, consider to upvote other answer with which you agree.</sup>

Comment: I edited the headers of both answers to make it clear at a glance which policy each answer is referring to.

Answer (score 5):

## [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

By consensus of community for changing the current policy to [the proposed one](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2329/277), **we are implementing the policy change now!**

Note: Before flagging the unsourced answer for deleting, kindly check the exclusion criteria (E2) and also try to improve/salvage the post if it's possible and providing useful content!

Feel free to discuss in [our main chat-room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15189/hinduism) for any clarification or support regarding this.

꧁༒☬  2021!☬༒꧂

Answer (score 1):

#### Keep the current policy (no change)

**Upvote this post** if you disagree with implementing the proposed policy and you want the **present policy to be continued** as represented below:

[image]

<sup>**Note**: Do not downvote this post if you disagree with this option, consider to upvote other answer with which you agree.</sup>